# mesh lines appear in quick rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, 3d-view, edges

I noticed in my last 2 blender files, that when i use subdivision surface, unwanted lines appear in quick rendering what is this? how can i fix that?[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `quick rendering`?

Comment: Maybe doubles in the mesh. Select all off it in edit and hit [Ctrl]+V > remove doubles.

Comment: i mean when i use viewport shading as rendered. However, the lines are not there when i use Render button (camera icon)

Comment: I just tried remove doubles, removed 0 vertices, didnt help, lines still appear in rendered viewport shading

Comment: Blender Internal or Cycles render engine? Also, could you add a pic of your node setup/settings?

Comment: okay i think i found the problem... its cycles.. Im using light path node (diffuse+shadow ray) -> add node - > to factor of mix shader(glass +transparent)... shadow ray causes that noise... how can i fix that so that,,,

Comment: Just an idea: try re UV unwrapping the mesh, sometimes if you edit a mesh after unwrapping you can get artifacts like this.

Comment: Christy James - didnt work, its the  Is shadow ray.... im using blender 2.73 but i think i didnt have problem with 2.71.... please any other ideas? or it might be version 2.73 in the end??? :(

Comment: Are there any inner faces? (faces inside the mesh)

Comment: Are you viewing this object in a camera/perspective view or orthographic?

Comment: well the glass was made of a cylinder so it has faces.... the problem is Is shadow ray... i want that ray but someone it is not displayed correctly...

Comment: Ray Mairlot  - yes u are right i had it in ortographic, when I switched to perspective, those annoying lines disappeared. Thanks mate !

Comment: why does orthographic view cause this?

Comment: @FishBone I am writing an answer

Comment: @FishBone If my answer helped, you can click the tick icon next to my answer to mark it as accepted. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 5):

The problem is only present in orthographic view. Changing to perspective or a camera view will fix this problem.

It's also why the issue isn't present in the final render, because most of the time you will be rendering with a perspective camera. You can actually zoom into any mesh in orthographic view and small cracks will start to appear on the mesh.

It is a known issue, with the [known issue page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/KnownIssues?) stating:

> When using Instancing, Motion Blur or Dynamic BVH, self-intersection may occur due to precision issues. Switching to Static BVH may avoid some problems but not all

There are several bug reports mentioning that this might be improved in future [here](https://developer.blender.org/T32332) and [here](https://developer.blender.org/T31384)