# Object surface be cracked when move too far grid center

Tags: mesh

I have a problem but i dont know how to describe it.
I have one object. It is look good if I put it in (0,0,0) xyz axis or about +- 100 unit location. But when i moved it to (1000,0,0) it became weird with some cracked on surface and it worse than that.
I applied locrotsccale already, just subsur modifier (but it not better when I removed modifier)
Some one help me how to fix it. Thank you
Here is my screenshot:
[image: when it on center]

[image: when I moved]

Update:
Here is my file to check [FILE](https://ufile.io/2kaim)

Comment: Don't use clipping values for the viewport camera ranging from 0.1 up to 3000, decrease the difference at least 3 times. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4946/where-can-the-viewport-clipping-parameters-be-changed

Comment: I tried to change chip value but it's not affect tho, by the way it only show up when I turn to rendered view, It look fine when solid view.

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26558/mesh-lines-appear-in-quick-rendering/26560#26560

Comment: @Ray Mairlot sorry but it doesn't help, I had checked many times my object that look good, clear geometry without material. This problem present although I tried to change ortho nor pers view. it also prensent when rendered. About clipping value, I let it default but didn't work too

Comment: Looks like creasing due to the subsurf modifier and some non-subsurf-friendly topology. Would it be possible to see a wireframe or (better yet) the .blend?

Comment: @gandalf3♦ I have just add my blend file, thank for your time

Comment: @baophan Huh, I've never seen anything like this! It seems to be [a numerical precision problem in cycles](https://developer.blender.org/T43835). As far as we're concerned from a user perspective, I'm not sure there really is a fix besides keeping the object closer to the origin.. Depending on what you're trying to do, perhaps we can come up with a workaround?

Comment: @gandalf3♦ I had created a big environment (a city)  and put my character to animated it. But when I move my char too far from center it became weird like that. Additional, I put char on a car and the car follow a long path so I can't control it.

Comment: @baophan I see. One possibly solution would be to separate the area the character stays in into a separate scene, moving it closer to the origin, then rendering both it and the far scene and compositing the two together. That would no doubt be a bit complicated to set up and might run into trouble if your animation is supposed to traverse a large distance without any cuts.

Comment: @baophan If that's the case, you might try animating the *city* moving long the path, keeping the camera close to the origin. That could prove rather annoying to manage, though it may be possible to have an addon take a normal animation apply the inverse as appropriate

Comment: Or poke the devs and see if they can make an up to date patch (I see there is a patch, but it apparently doesn't work with the latest version)

Comment: @gandalf3♦ thank you so much, I put my question into another forum and the answer is a bug of cycle, I will try to separate my scene and waiting for a patch too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to [an old bug](https://developer.blender.org/T43835). The cause has [been identified](https://developer.blender.org/T43835#296321):

> The issue is actually coming from the way how ray bounce is happening: it is using `ray_offset()` in order to avoid self-intersection. This function will push ray along the face normal by a small value. This small value is different for different axis and actually depends on magnitude of the original coordinate. In this case ray is getting pushed a bit more along Y axis than along X and Z axis. This makes ray to be moved into the surface itself, causing light artifacts.

But it's apparently difficult to solve. There is [a patch](https://developer.blender.org/T43835#296321) you can try if you are familiar with building software, but you'll likely have to apply it to an older version of blender (and it doesn't fix everything).